# WAMP PHP 5.4.3 32-Bit cURL Extension?

Tags: php, wamp

Does anyone know where a compiled **32-bit cURL for PHP 5.4.3** is? 
Because the cURL that comes with the latest WAMP is not valid.

Since I'm on 32-bit Windows I can't run the file from here:

http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/